# Change start angle/ first slice angle of PIE chart in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have a pie chart with multiple segments in it. I want certain pie segment to start from an angle I provide. [image: pie chart image]

Comment: Please include a picture. How does a pie chart have multiple pies in it? Which segment do you want to start where? What does it do by default?

Comment: Hey @scanny! For our project, I edited `/c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:doughnutChart/c:firstSliceAng`. The default value had 0 and I changed it to 270 and it works just fine. But note that the pie chart I'm working with only had 1 series in it. Try with your chart and let us know if it works.

Comment: Actually I meant multiple segments. Editing the above issue and adding image. I want pediasure at 70 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to change firstSliceAng of piechart in python-pptx:

1. Check whether firstSliceAng tags exist or not:

```
firstSliceAng = pieChart.xpath("./c:firstSliceAng")
print(firstSliceAng)

Expected output: 
[<some-object>]
```

If the list is blank, then it means you need to add firstSliceAng using lxml or oxml

To add it with lxml use following steps:

```
    tag = tags[0]
    child = OxmlElement('c:firstSliceAng')
    # keep in mind that **start_angle** should always be string whose value is int and not float
    **start_angle = str(int(75.55))**
    child.set('val', start_angle+45)
    tag.addprevious(child)
```

To add it with lxml use following steps:

````
    doc = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
    root = doc.getroot()
    # keep in mind that **start_angle** should always be string whose value is int and not float
    **start_angle = str(int(75.55))**
    c = Element(QName(root.nsmap['c'], 'firstSliceAng'), val=start_angle)
    present_element = chart.plots[0]._element.xpath('c:varyColors')[0]
    present_element.addprevious(c)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Pie chart "rotation" features in PowerPoint are limited to positioning the "start" angle of the first segment, with segments growing in the clockwise direction only.

So you can specify that the first element appears at 70-degrees (clockwise from the 12-o'clock position).

Currently there is no API support for this, but the value is in the XML at the location mentioned by @Saleh above: `/c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:pieChart/c:firstSliceAng`

You can access the `c:doughnutChart` element on:

```
chart.plots[0]._element
```

And print it with:

```
print(chart.plots[0]._element.xml)
```

If it happens to already have a `c:firstSliceAng` element on it, you can just change the setting, perhaps something like this:

```
pieChart = chart.plots[0]._element
firstSliceAng = pieChart.xpath("./c:firstSliceAng")
firstSliceAng["val"] = "70"
```

If there is no firstSliceAng element there you need to use `lxml` calls to add it first.